# How can I merge multiple Unwraped faces of a single object into one image texture?

Tags: texture-baking, uv-image-editor

I'm currently trying to bake a single image texture of a single object, but I'm having trouble with UV of this object. All faces look like they are unwraped individually and I need them to be all unwraped as a whole. I tried to select them all and do a smart UV project but doing that will mess up their position.

I'm not too familiar with the UV Editing tab and the object is imported using an addon called MCprep. The only thing I can think of that maybe could fix the issue is to some how be able to merge all UV images into one but I don't know how.

I will try to explain it more simply by telling how the issue might get caused.

The whole thing is like having the default cube being open in UV edit tab and then a single face is selected and smart UV project is applied to it, then the process is repeated for all other faces. I need to somehow have them All together into a single image that I can bake.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add a new UV map to all objects for the baking. The original UV maps will be used with the current (source) textures, and the new UV maps will be used for the texture to be baked (destination). You will need to edit all of the objects together to pack their new UV maps into the 0 to 1 UV space so they share the new texture.

I suggest to follow [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4Ajd06eTak) for more information. It's for lightmap baking, but it covers general baking steps that will help you here. In your case, you will be baking Diffuse Color if I understand your setup correctly.

Comment: Is there by any chance an add - on that can also do that but without all of the hustle to setup nodes and bake settings?

Comment: I've written an add-on to do that before. I haven't posted it anywhere, though. I still need to review and clean the code. If you share the file in your question, I can run the add-on on my end and send the processed assets back to you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I found out about an addon called simple bake that does the whole process for me.